# How to open a modal dialog in Java applet?

Tags: java, applet, dialog

I'm trying to display a modal dialog in front of an `Applet`.

My current solution fetches the root frame like so:

```
Frame getMyParent() {
    Container parent = getParent();
    while (!(parent instanceof Frame)) {
        parent = ((Component)parent).getParent();
    }
    return (Frame)parent;
}
```

And creates the dialog as follows:

```
public OptionsDialog(MainApplet applet, boolean modal) {
    super(applet.getMyParent(), "options", modal);
    // ....
```

However often this shows the modal dialog **below** the frame, though the modal behaviour works correctly.

How can this be fixed?

Ideally this should be for Java versions 1.5 and above.

Answer (score 4):

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog(SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(this));
dialog.setModal(true);
dialog.setSize(200, 200);
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thanks camickr. Unfortunately this requires version 1.6 and I'm stuck with supporting Java 1.5 (as a lot of people still use this). Apologies for not clarifying, I have edited the question.

Comment: I'm not aware of any code I posted being unique to version 1.6.

Comment: I found the JDialog(Window) constructor is 1.6 specific: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog(java.awt.Window)

Comment: Ok, so the constructor that takes a Window is from 1.6, but there are many other constructors to use. I'm betting you are actually using a JFrame as the owner Window, so just cast the Window to a JFrame. There is a constructor thats takes a Frame and a JFrame extends Frame.

Comment: Thanks camickr. Sorry for the delay. I tried testing to see whether windowForComponent was a JFrame, but no luck `java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginEmbeddedFrame cannot be cast to javax.swing.JFrame`

Answer (score 3):

Frame f =(Frame)SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(Frame.class,parentWindow);
new JDialog(f,true);

(source = http://kb.trisugar.com/node/7613)
works for parentWindow = sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginEmbeddedFrame

Answer (score 2):

Use **null** insterad of `applet.getMyParent()`

Comment: Hmmm, using null will set the owner frame to `SwingUtilities.getSharedOwnerFrame()` - I will test, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this does not resolve the problem, I have only tested with Chrome and it consistently shows below the page.